# ViewFlipper with only 1 layout?

Tags: android, layout, viewflipper

Following is the xml code/ layout used for my activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ViewFlipper
android:layout_margin="6dip"
android:id="@+id/layoutswitcher"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:textSize="27dp" android:text="Word" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@+id/wordText" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"></TextView>

    <TextView android:textSize="20dp" android:text="Meaning" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@+id/meaningText" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/wordText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
     android:layout_marginTop="34dp"></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/meaningBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:editable="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/meaningText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
     <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <TextView android:textSize="20dp" android:text="Usage" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:textColor="@color/black" android:id="@+id/usageText" 
     android:layout_below="@+id/meaningBox" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"> 
     </TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/usageBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:editable="false" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/usageText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></EditText>

    <CheckBox style="?android:attr/starStyle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/bookmark" 
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wordText"          
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/wordText">
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have only 1 layout in viewflipper. I change only values in same layout when user swipes finger on screen for next and previous.
Then i have added animations for next and previous. I am doing it with following code

```
vs.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_animation1);
vs.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_animation1);
vs.showNext();
```

In this animations are not working as stated in animations xml file.
When user swipes 1st view is not fading away , it just disappears and next view come.
But same animations files are working when I add another layout in view flipper.
Can anyone tell me what is problem ?
or How should I work when there is only one layout in view flipper ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about why you only have 1 view inside of the ViewFlipper. I believe that the point of the flipper is to transition between several views.

Your java code looks correct, however when you call vs.showNext() there is nothing there for your ViewFlipper to transition to. No transitions means now animations.